# Can PetaPoco populate an object using a stored procedure with a join clause?

Tags: stored-procedures, orm, petapoco

I have a stored procedure that does something similar to:

```
SELECT a.TaskId, b.CompanyCode FROM task a JOIN company b ON b.CompanyId = a.CompanyId;
```

I have an object called TaskItem that has the TaskId and CompanyCode properties, but when I execute the following (which I would have assumed worked):

```
        var masterDatabase = new Database("MasterConnectionString");
        var s = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Append("EXEC spGetTasks @@numberOfTasks = @0", numberOfTasks);
        var tasks = masterDatabase.Query<TaskItem>(s);
```

The problem is that the CompanyCode column does not exist in the task table, I did a trace and it seems that PetaPoco is trying to select all the properties from the task table and populating using the stored procedure.

Here is a definition of TaskItem:

```
public class TaskItem {
    public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use PetaPoco to simply populate the list of task objects with the results of the stored procedure?

Comment: it would help if you showed definition of `TaskItem`

Comment: Sorry @Dmitry, just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need two columns from the database, don't bother with POCOs. Use dynamic:

```cs
var d = masterDatabase.Query<dynamic>("Exec spGetTasks @@numberOfTasks = @0", numberOfTasks);
var result = d.Select(item => new Tuple<int, string>(item.TaskId, item.CompanyCode)).ToList();
```

otherwise the POCO that you are using to query database, i.e. `TaskItem` need to have a public property for each column name returned by the query.

**UPDATE**
Now that you've posted definition of `TaskItem` I see that you have all the properties that you need on it. In theory it is enough to have a public property with the exact same name as the returned column for it to be populated. So in your case since query returns column `CompanyCode`, the appropriate property should be populated on the `TaskItem`. In case the property name differs, you can map it by decorating it with `[Column]` attribute

```
[Column("NameOfTheColumn")]
public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
```

If for some reason `CompanyCode` still remains not populated, the issue is with the query. Make sure that it returns appropriate results.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, but what if the object started to get more complex, with say 5 or 10 properties?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, but how am I retrieving and populating the data?  If I use the masterDatabase.Fetch, it complains that the Task table doesn't contain CompanyCode.  If I use your dynamic way, I'm stuck populating each field individually (at that point I don't see the advantage of using the ORM)

Comment: I don't know why it would complain about CompanyCode. It's clearly is returned by your query. Try using `.Query<TaskItem>`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, the problem is that it assumes the column belongs to the task table, but I fixed this by creating a Company object and doing a fetch on <Task, Company>.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `dynamic` as @Dmitry points, you can add the property to the `TaskItem` POCO, and decorate it with `ResultColumn`

```
    [ResultColumn]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo, that worked, but the CompanyCode was not populated, was left blank, how can I tell PetaPoco to map the resulting CompanyCode column to the property?